# Django: Factory for data

Tags: django

I'm looking to generate mock up model data that's also makes sense from a content standpoint. E.g., real name randomizer, address randomizer etc. Is thee such a library somewhere that handles that?

I'd appreciate a pointer in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe `faker` may be of assistance here...

https://github.com/joke2k/faker

From the docs:

```
from faker import Faker
fake = Faker()

fake.name()
# 'Lucy Cechtelar'

fake.address()
# "426 Jordy Lodge
#  Cartwrightshire, SC 88120-6700"

fake.text()
# Sint velit eveniet. Rerum atque repellat voluptatem quia rerum. Numquam excepturi
# beatae sint laudantium consequatur. Magni occaecati itaque sint et sit tempore. Nesciunt
# amet quidem. Iusto deleniti cum autem ad quia aperiam.
# A consectetur quos aliquam. In iste aliquid et aut similique suscipit. Consequatur qui
# quaerat iste minus hic expedita. Consequuntur error magni et laboriosam. Aut aspernatur
# voluptatem sit aliquam. Dolores voluptatum est.
# Aut molestias et maxime. Fugit autem facilis quos vero. Eius quibusdam possimus est.
# Ea quaerat et quisquam. Deleniti sunt quam. Adipisci consequatur id in occaecati.
# Et sint et. Ut ducimus quod nemo ab voluptatum.
```